# The XPath query expression "/PX_CDUSAGE[CODE_FOR_REFERENCE=]" is invalid

Tags: java, websphere-commerce, wcs

User receiving this error while applying promotion code, I have researched a lot but couldn't find the reason for this error.

Environment is IBM Websphere Commerce 7, DB2.

```
com.ibm.commerce.order.calculation.FinalizeDiscountCalculationUsageCmdImpl performExecute CMN3201E: 
An unknown error occurred while the Rules System was processing.. 
com.ibm.commerce.marketing.promotion.runtime.PromotionRuntimeException: 
com.ibm.commerce.exception.ECApplicationException: 
A generic promotion system exception occured.  The exception is as follows: 
"The XPath query expression "/PX_CDUSAGE[CODE_FOR_REFERENCE=]" is invalid."
at com.ibm.commerce.marketing.promotion.runtime.PromotionArgument.finalizePromotionArgument(PromotionArgument.java:868)
at com.ibm.commerce.order.calculation.FinalizeDiscountCalculationUsageCmdImpl.performExecute(FinalizeDiscountCalculationUsageCmdImpl.java:104)
at com.ibm.commerce.command.ECCommandTarget.executeCommand(ECCommandTarget.java:157)
at com.ibm.ws.cache.command.CommandCache.executeCommand(CommandCache.java:332)
```

I have been trying to figure out the root cause of this error since 2 days but couldn't find anything.Any help would highly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The xpath expression is nog complete. It should be something like:

```
"/PX_CDUSAGE[CODE_FOR_REFERENCE='forgotten']"
```

Comment: I thought it was your own code. If it is not, then the only solution is to contact the one who delivers this application.